# Automating `mysql_secure_installation` Using GoLang

Tags: linux, go, buffer, build-automation

The third command `RunCommand("mysql_secure_installation");` doesn't show stdout/stderr buffers and command will not finish. Keyboard typing works but doesn't affect the process.

The `mysql_secure_installation` on ssh console works perfect.

Other commands work perfectly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "os"
    "bufio"
)

func main() {
    RunCommand("lsb_release -a"); //works perfect
    RunCommand("apt-get update"); //works perfect
    RunCommand("mysql_secure_installation"); //empty output and waiting for something!
}

func RunCommand(command string) {
    args := []string {"-c", command}
    executer := exec.Command("sh", args...)

    stdout, err := executer.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("Error creating STDOUT pipe")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    stderr, err := executer.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("Error creating STDERR pipe")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    stdoutScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    stdoutScanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    go func() {
        for stdoutScanner.Scan() {
            out := stdoutScanner.Text();
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)
        }
    }()

    stderrScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stderr)
    stderrScanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    go func() {
        for stderrScanner.Scan() {
            error := stderrScanner.Text()
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", error)
        }
    }()

    err = executer.Start()
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    err = executer.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

The main problem found and asked as new question in this link: [How to store STDOUT buffer of `mysql_secure_installation` to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47087442/1290995)

**UPDATE 2:**

CentOS and Debian tested and buffer works perfect but on my target os ( Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ) it doesn't work.

Comment: also using `bufio.ScanRunes` as scanner not worked

Comment: must be waiting for password? try commenting other two commands and just try to RunCommand for mysql_secure...

Comment: @sahaj single running the command, desn't work again. also as mentioned typing with keyboard no affect the process ( with enter , ... )

Comment: I get the password prompt on go version go1.9.2 linux/amd64.

Comment: @sahaj I use version 1.6.2, many thanks for reminding an update. I'll test it soon.

Comment: @sahaj I tested version 1.9.2 but not worked and the problem persists.

Comment: I found new problem that may be main reason to this question that asked in this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/47087442/1290995

Answer (score 0):

The reason it hangs is because it is still waiting for user input to complete.

As mentioned in the comments, [`mysql_secure_installation`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-secure-installation.html) requires user input. If you want to run it without user input, you can try adding the `--use-default` argument.

If you want to wait for use input, then consider reading up on the difference between [`Run`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run) and [`Start`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start). From the documentation:

> Run starts the specified command and waits for it to complete.

> Start starts the specified command but does not wait for it to complete.

You may need to experiment with using `Run` to allow user input to the program. Alternately, you could probably redirect another string into the command using stdin, but that might be more complicated than it's worth.

Comment: I wrote a large framework to do task like this, handling stdin exist as part of it worked perfecly with other process in non-interactive way. but I seperate code to simplify test without stdin and for presenting in stackoverflow. I need prompting for values but even the initial message doesn't show and no help when type and press enter character repeatly.
Also I handled reading from STDIN to check if buffer presented in that but not help again.

Comment: also no luck running with `Run` method that tested before asking question