# How to store STDOUT buffer of `mysql_secure_installation` to a file

Tags: linux, bash, buffer, sh

I want to append STDOUT or STDERR of command `mysql_secure_installation` to a file for example `/tmp/output.txt` but no success on below commands:

```
mysql_secure_installation >> /tmp/output.txt
mysql_secure_installation 1>> /tmp/output.txt
mysql_secure_installation 2>> /tmp/output.txt
```

Also tested STDIN and reserved buffers by below commands:

```
mysql_secure_installation 0>> /tmp/output.txt
mysql_secure_installation 3>> /tmp/output.txt
...
mysql_secure_installation 9>> /tmp/output.txt
```

It seems `mysql_secure_installation` output buffers is many different from other commands and it's buffer cannot accessible. Is this true and how to handle it?

**UPDATE 1:**

CentOS tested and buffer works perfect but on my target os ( Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ) it doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2:**

Worked on Debian 9 too, but problem on ( Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ) exists.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/scripts/mysql_secure_installation.sh), `echo` is used normally to output to stdout. I'm sure you've seen it, but just in case, try checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270733/automate-mysql-secure-installation-with-echo-command-via-a-shell-script)

Comment: @Addison Thanks for your comment and linking source. You are right. `echo` used for generating output, but i don't know why won't work. About automating using batch, I saw it before by not solve my problem or anything to clearify it.

Comment: Well, I might try to replicate this on a LiveCD if I get a chance this weekend. It's an interesting problem